# why is Inkwell not assigned to the parameter Widget?

Tags: flutter

I am wondering why a wrapped Inkwell widget is not working on a simple flutter screen. The code is the following:

```
class SearchButtonState extends State<SearchButton> {
  bool folded = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        width: folded ? 56 : 200,
        height: 56,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
          color: Color(0xFF88B4E0),
          boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[6],
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                child: !folded
                    ? TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                            border: InputBorder.none),
                      )
                    : null,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                //fixing splash
                child: Material(
                    type: MaterialType.transparency,
                    child: Inkwell(
                      //Fixing the BorderRadius of the Splash
                      BorderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(folded ? 32 : 0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(32),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(folded ? 32 : 0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(32),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          folded ? Icons.search : Icons.close,
                          color: Color(0xFF88B4E0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          folded = !folded;
                        });
                      },
                    )))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

The error is the following: "The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'widget'". I would appreciate if someone know why do I get this error, since the Inkwell is wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code `Inkwell` to `InkWell` and `BorderRadius:` to `borderRadius:`

```
child: Material(
     type: MaterialType.transparency,
     child: InkWell(
      //Fixing the BorderRadius of the Splash
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
...
```